# window.print not working tried all methods in all major browsers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print a page with window.print but it ain't working in all the browsers.

This is the code that i am using:

```
<div class="user_buttons">
    <!--Test 1-->
    <A HREF="javascript:window.print()"><IMG SRC="images/print.png" BORDER="0"</A>

    <!--Test 2--> 
    <FORM>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="window.print()">
    </FORM>

    <!--Test 3-->
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
    if (window.print) {
        document.write('<form><input type=button name=print value="Print" onClick="window.print()"></form>');
    }
    </script>

    <!--Test 4-->
    <img src="images/print.png" onclick="window.print()">
    <div><a href="overzicht.php"><img src="images/overzicht.png" title="Terug naar overzicht"></a></div> 
</div>
```

As you can see i am trying multiple solutions given by the internet. What is frustrating is that those codes are working on the demo sites but they aren't on my page. I post my code in JSF. The JSF example will not be a working example but it will have the entire code in the javascript area. The link for the entire code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7bRNu/

Comment: I'm fairly sure all of those should work. How do you establish that they "don't work"? ie. what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Did u check your jsfiddle?I request you to check it before post your link..

Comment: Your fiddle has HTML in the Javascript box. That's not going to work.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen = When i load the webpage in my browser and I click on them it is not giving me the print screen. So it aint working. Joke_Sense10 and Barmar I said in my question that i put the entire code of the page in the javascript area. And yes the JSF is not working but adding 748 rows of code in stackoverflow is very irritating with the 4 spaces in front of each row. So I put it in JSF which is only once CTRL+V. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: I cleaned the code up a bit, put it in the right boxes and removed all the PHP code and unnecessary stuff that does not belong in the fiddle. Turns out `window.print` works. http://jsfiddle.net/7bRNu/1/

Comment: @Butt4cak3: Can you tell me why it ain't working on my site. Is there a conflict somewhere??? I am glad that it is working on JSF but I will be SUPER happy when it is working on my site.

Comment: @HennySmafter The only thing I can say is that window.print is *".$row[* instead of a function. Why and how that happened? I don't know.

Comment: you can test it in firefox with web developer plugin and see what the javascript error is. it will help you

Comment: @Butt4cak3 I dont understand: window.print is ".$row[ instead of a function

Comment: please paste the generated html, not the one with php-related code.

Comment: @HennySmafter `window.print` is overwritten, for some reason. Look at this: http://puu.sh/4T2Yw.png

Comment: @Butt4cak3 Thank you I am clever in some things but this I have no idea what it means. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Apostolos How can I paste the generated HTML.

Comment: put it in jsf too or pastebin.maybe a php-generated code breaks the functionality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got it. It was a very painfull process of searching errors in a huge mess of code. **The next time you ask a question on stackoverflow, please make sure that you broke the problem down into smaller pieces and post only the code that you think is probably the cause of your problem.**

In the very bottom of your entire code, there is a little script-section in which it says:

```
var print = document.getElementById("print").value;
```

You are in the global scope, meaning that every variable you declare will be a property of `window`. Therefore, by writing `print =` you actually redefine `window.print`. Change the name of this variable and you should be good. The following line is only an example. You can choose whatever variable name you like. Just don't use `print`.

```
var printValue = document.getElementById("print").value;
```

Comment: Shall i delete that entire script section or just rename "print" to "irritatingcode"

Comment: @HennySmafter As I said, you only have to rename the variable `print` to anything you like. Maybe to `printValue` or something like that. Just don't use `print`, as it means the same as `window.print`.

Comment: I was confused with variable you mean the `var print` i thought you meant the `"print"`. I am changing it now but I can't test it right now my IP is blocked because I tried to many uploads and refreshed in the last hour. I need to wait for my IP to become unblocked again. But thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method isolated:

http://jsfiddle.net/5PumN/

```
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()"><IMG SRC="images/print.png" BORDER="0"</A>
```

It works just fine here.

Comment: All the methods are working. I know this. The only problem is they are not working on my page. Somehow when all the codes are deleted in the page except for the userdiv. Then it is working. But obviously I cant delete all this code because then the page has no sense at all.

Comment: Then, with the information you've given us, we can't solve your problem.