# Print function not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to print a table using jquery function, but while clicking 'print' button I only got empty page. Data couldn't load to the page.

My code

```
<script>
function print_click(divname)
  {
    var printcontents = document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML;
    var originalcontents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalcontents;
  }
```

```
  <div runat="server" id="studentlist">
         <asp:Label id="statuslabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          <table  style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:35px">
           <tr  style="height:20px;padding-left:30px;">
             <th runat="server" id="regno" style="color:white">REG NO</th>
             <th runat="server" id="studname" style="color:white">STUDENT NAME</th>
             <th runat="server" id="dept" style="color:white">DEPARTMENT</th>
             <th runat="server" id="degre" style="color:white">CGPA</th>
             <th runat="server" id="twlth" style="color:white">%IN XII</th>
             <th runat="server" id="cnum" style="color:white">CONTACT NO</th>

           </tr> 
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">  
         <itemtemplate>
          <tr style="margin-left:100px">
            <td style="width:120px;"> 
             <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reg_no") %>' /></td>
            <td style="width:120px;padding-right:0px"> 
             <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("student_name") %>' /></td>
            <td style="width:120px"> 
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("department_name") %>' /></td>
            <td style="width:120px"> 
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" style="height:130px;width:120px;" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image_name")%>'/></td>
            <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="dwnload" Text="Download Image">
            </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </itemtemplate>
       </asp:ListView>
      </table>
     </div>

    <input  runat="server"  type="button"  name="Print" value="print" class="mybtn" id="prntbtn"  onclick="print_click('studentlist')"/>
```

I have an html button and "onclick" Button click is working fine, but the print page wouldn't have data.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449517/window-print-not-working-tried-all-methods-in-all-major-browsers